# Generating .pfm image in c++

Tags: c++, image-processing, pbm

I have a small program that outputs an rgb image. And I need it to be in .pfm format.

So, I have some data in the range `[0, 255]`.

```
float * data;
data = new float[PixelWidth * PixelHeight * 3];
for (int i = 0; i < PixelWidth * PixelHeight * 3; i += 3) {
    int idx = i / 3;
    data[i] = img[idx].x;
    data[i + 1] = img[idx].y;
    data[i + 2] = img[idx].z;
}
```

(`img[]` here is `Vec3[]` of `unsigned char`)

Now I generate the image.

```
char sizes[256];
f = fopen("outputimage.pfm", "wb");
double scale = -1.0;
fprintf(f, "PF\n%d %d\n%lf\n", PixelWidth, PixelHeight, scale);
for (int i = 0; i < PixelWidth*PixelHeight*3; i++) {
    float d = data[i];
    fwrite((void *)&d, 1, 4, f);
}
fclose(f);
```

But somehow I get a grayscale image instead of RGB.

The data is fine. I tried to output it as .ppm and it works fine.

I guess the problem is with scaling, but I am not really sure how it should be done correctly.

Comment: `img[idx].x;` & `(img[] here is unsigned char*)`. Hmm, something seems wrong here. Can you show us how `img` is defined?

Comment: Sorry, I meant it's Vec3 of `unsigned char`.

Comment: Why are you using `float` to store integral numbers? Why are you using `fopen` etc. in C++ code?

Comment: @EdHeal Using ppm images was enough for me until now. But now I want to use some third-party library and it works only with .pfm. So, I am trying to make a converter from .ppm to .pfm. And since .pfm uses floats instead of integers(like .ppm) I am having problems with it.

Comment: Is it working now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To close the question.

I just had to convert all the values from `[0-255]` range to `[0.0-1.0]`. So, I divided each rgb value by 255.